# How to capture right click in a MacCatalyst app?

Tags: swift, mac-catalyst, uikitformac

How can I present a context menu or even better a iOS Popover controller when right clicking in a MacCatalyst app? Right now I have it set up for long presses, not that doesn't feel right on a desktop app.

Answer (score 3):

https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/controls/context-menus/
We use this to develop right click menus with MacCatalyst